# AngularJS promises and timing with custom filters

Tags: angularjs, filter, timing, promise

I'm having a massive headache right now regarding custom filters timing.
 I have a demo (learning Angular) gallery app in which I am using a custom filter with checkboxes to select different categories of photos.

The Simptoms: when using a custom filter on a ng-repeat directive I noticed this http://screencast.com/t/xPGX1lyTu9Yp  ... after a few hours of debugging I got to the conclusion that the problem is that the **data from my JSON is not there when the filter runs**, though without the filter everything seems to load ok.

**Here is a plnkr for this http://plnkr.co/edit/KbBg67** (I copy pasted the code, modified it a bit, not working yet, will fix it in the morning, but this is the code)

I started using deferring and promises in my services with fetches the JSON data so I the controllers and everybody else would wait for the data to load, like this [SERVICES]

```
angular.module('services', []).factory('getAllPosts', ['$http', '$q', '$timeout',
function($http, $q, $timeout) {
  //defining the promised based API
  var deffered = $q.defer();
  //the getData function
  var getData = function() {
    //defining a empty data array
    var theData = {};
    //using $http to get the dat
    $http.get('/wordpress/api/get_recent_posts/').success(function(data) {
      // prepare data here
      //assigning our data to the theData array.
      // // New stuff here, we are pushing the data one by one to populate the array faster so it isn't emtpy .. ?!
      theData.length = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        theData.push(data[i]);
      }
      theData = data;
    });
    //setting a timeout for the data and waiting if necesarry.
    $timeout(function() {
      deffered.resolve(theData);
    }, 1000);
    //when it s done, return the promise... i think so. ?!
    return deffered.promise;
  }
  return {
    //creating a getData handler to use in controllers.
    getData: getData
  };
}])
```

My controller is like this [CONTROLLER]

```
.controller('ListController', ['$scope', 'getAllPosts', 'getCategories', '$location',
    function($scope, getAllPosts, getCategories) {
        $scope.name = 'list';
        getAllPosts.getData().then(function(data) {
            return $scope.posts = data.posts;
        });
        getCategories.get(function(data){
            return $scope.categories = data.categories;
        })
    }
])
```

I'm using getData().then() to fetch it while it's loaded.

I realize I am not telling the same thing to the filter [FILTER]

```
angular.module('filters', [])
.filter('checkboxFilter', function($filter) {
    return function(post, prefs) {
        var i, j, k, n, out, matchingpost = [];
        // loop through the post
        for (i = 0; i < post.length; i++) {
            console.log('I passed the length ... wtf?')
            out = false;
            n = 0;

            if (prefs) {
                // for each item, loop through the checkboxes categories
                for (j = 0; j < prefs.length; j++) {

                    // for each category, loop through the checkboxes categories of the current category
                    for (k = 0; k < prefs[j].categories.length; k++) {

                        // test if the current item property name is the same as the filter name
                        if (post[i][prefs[j].slug] === prefs[j].categories[k].slug) {

                            // test if checkbox is checked for this property 
                            (prefs[j].categories[k].value) ? n++ : out = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (out) break;
                    // if one filter in each categories is true, add item to the matchingpost
                    if (n === prefs.length) {
                        matchingpost.push(post[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return matchingpost;
    }
})
```

The thing is I started reading a angular book and I didn't understood many things so I went for a hands on experience, slowly every bit falls into place but this one  ... I've been spending to much time on it. I think if I take it on again it will make much more sense.

---

Question: How could I get rid of those errors and make the filter read the data after it's been loaded?

---

Side-Question: Through a different service I am outputting all the existing categories in my backbone (Wordpress) and ng-repeat them in checkboxes, how would I link the checkboxes to the results of this filters? (it isn't obvious to me yet, though I have already seen some examples....)

---

Side-Question 2: Why do all my requests multiply, as in the first screenshot I posted, no wait, this is the part I am talking about http://screencast.com/t/lcrWnlioL3u ... I have only 44 posts so far, but it look like even after the data is there, the filter calls for it again.

This behaviour hapenned on other things too ... I am wondering what am I doing wrong.

---

Annotation: I am using angular 1.2.0rc1 as of tonight, all the behaviors appeared with the other versions I used:  1.0.7.0, 1.1.5.

Comment: Here a screenshot describing the problem http://screencast.com/t/lTr6Q3M5sL  .... I used another approach to make the filter skip the undefined posts array `if (post == undefined) {
    console.log('post is mush');
   } else {`      I'm checking to see if it's undefined, if not it's gonna loop until the posts load ... I AM CERTAIN this is not the way to go, but for the moment it works.  http://screencast.com/t/U8ITGi7w3s7g (it loops 4 times through undefined and then it enters the correct filter function.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the real way to do this would be to override the default `$interpolateProvider` to enable filters that return promises. That way, you could defer the rendering of certain filtered expressions until they are resolved.

Remember, though, that you cannot do this for chained filters trivially. You will probably be forced to rewrite `$parse` as well to enable support for chaining of promises.

I am faced with the very same problem at the moment, and as such, I might go ahead and just do it. If so, I will make sure to post a link to the answer on the github repository for my project (http://github.com/agileapes/bootstrapui).

**EDIT**

Another (mostly) easy way to do it is to pass an arbitrary argument to your filter that is updated via the HTTP call (or any other means):

```
.controller("MyController", function ($scope, $q, $timeout) {
    $scope.result = null;
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.result = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    }, 2000);
});
```

here I have just updated the result via a timeout, but I don't have to do it that way. This is just for demonstration. You could update `$scope.result` in any way you choose.

Here is a sample filter, that will only include *even* numbers in the result:

```
.filter('even', function () {
    return function (input) {
        if (!angular.isArray(input)) {
            return input;
        }
        var result = [];
        angular.forEach(input, function (x) {
            if (x % 2 == 0) {
                result.push(x);
            }
        });
        return result;
    }
});
```

Now, in my view, I can use them together, this way:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <ul ng-if="result.length"> <!-- It is nice to not pollute the DOM with empty lists -->
        <li ng-repeat="item in result | even">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

After a couple of seconds or so, the list should be populated and the `ngRepeat` directive should receive the filtered result.

The trick, here, is that I have made a digest cycle happen for that particular `result` variable, which means that the filter that is being fed that variable will also be re-executed, which in turns means that everything will happen smoothly and as expected.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create your own promise as the AngularJS `$http` service already does this for you.

So your service can be simplified like this:

```
angular.module('services', []).factory('getAllPosts', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        getData: function() {

            // Return the promise that is created by the $http service
            return $http.get('/wordpress/api/get_recent_posts/')
        }
    };
}]);
```

Then in your controller:

```
angular.module('yourModule')
.controller('ListController', ['$scope', 'getAllPosts',
    function($scope, getAllPosts) {

        $scope.items = []; // Placeholder for the data

        getAllPosts.getData()
            .success(function(data, status, header, config){

                 // Fill placeholder with data as soon as it is received
                 $scope.items = data;
            });
    }
]);
```

Then in your view, you can use the `ng-model` directive or `ng-repeat` directive to show your data like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
    {{item.someProperty}}
</li>
```

If you want to apply your custom filter, just use:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items | your_filter">
    {{item.someProperty}}
</li>
```

AngularJS will automatically take care of updating the view when `$scope.items` is updated, so you don't need to write extra code for that.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is how the rest of my controllers are, just what you wrote up there

Comment: Can you create a plnkr?

Comment: Here is the plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/KbBg67    Will tinker with it to make it work properly (if I don t fall asleep), I made it locally then uploaded the pieces to plnkr.

Comment: EDIT: Just add  in <li ng-repeat="post in posts | filter:searchPostName"> "| checkboxFilter" and watch it break. It won't go through my list, although I don't know how it will behave with a json file on hand, on my machine it takes a while for the server to respond ~1 sec.

Comment: I forked your plnkr and created a working version for your convenience: http://plnkr.co/edit/3EoTdH?p=preview

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll see what's what this evening after work. Your filter function is so short, in the latest iteration I wrote a lot of code :)) .. bad code!!!

Comment: At first glance I see that you are filtering through the posts name.  The post is a JSON object that can have several categories, What I did in my plnkr is to filter each categories object from the main post object with the categories object.

Comment: Nonetheless what you did there might help me, I'll adapt to filter through the existing categories.

Answer (score 0):

```
//defining a empty data array
var theData = {};
```

This is an object definition, not an array definition. Try to replace it by

```
var theData = [];
```

It might solve your issue.

Comment: That was a typo from last night, I wrote and rewrote a lot of code. Thanks. Data stopped coming from my service. All the other problems are still there though, duplication of data, filter timing issue

Answer (score 0):

**It seems that - though rather costly - the way to fix this is to loop until the information arrives.** - any other solutions are welcomed.

Like this:

```
.filter('checkboxFilter', function() {
    return function(post, prefs) {
        //define empty vars, strict mode
        var i, j, k, n, out, matchingpost = [];
        //check to see if the posts have arrived
        if (post == undefined) {
            //posts are not here yet            
        } else {
            //posts have arrived.
            //iterate through all the posts
            for (i = 0; i < post.length; i++) {
                out = false;
                n = 0;
                var eachPostCategories = post[i].categories;
                //console.log(eachPostCategories)
                for (j = 0; j < eachPostCategories.length; j++) {
                    //console.log(' post categories are');
                    //console.log(eachPostCategories[j]);
                    if (prefs == undefined) {
                        //preferences aren't in yet
                    } else {
                        //preferences are here.
                        //now we should iterate through all the preferences and compare them to the posts.
                        for (k = 0; k < prefs.length; k++) {
                            //prefs[j].slug
                            //console.log('categories are');
                            //console.log(prefs[k].slug)
                            if (eachPostCategories[j].slug === prefs[k].slug) {
                                //console.log('this post has the categories');
                                //console.log(post[i]);

                                //WHAT DOES THIS LINE MEAN?
                                /*(prefs[k].slug) ? n++ : out = true;
                                break;*/
                                n++
                            } else {
                                out = true;
                                break;
                            }
                            console.log('n is ' + n);
                        }
                        if (out) break;
                        // if one filter in each categories is true, add item to the matchingpost
                        if (n === prefs.length) {
                            matchingpost.push(post[i]);
                        }

                    }
                }

            }
        }
        if (matchingpost.length == 0) {
            //return matchingpost = post
        } else {
            return matchingpost;
        }

    }
})
```

The filter is not perfect yet, every object is duplicated, I can hide the elements based on their categories, but I cannot make them show up :|

I don't seem to graps the concept, if someone can give me some pointers it would be awesome.

As a general idea, I am comparing an object like:

```
    debug: [{"id":2,"slug":"architecture","title":"Architecture","description":"","parent":0,"post_count":16,"selected":"true"},{"id":13,"slug":"day","title":"Day","description":"","parent":0,"post_count":37,"selected":"true"},{"id":7,"slug":"funny","title":"Funny","description":"","parent":0,"post_count":6,"selected":"true"},{"id":4,"slug":"landscape","title":"Landscape","description":"","parent":0,"post_count":12,"selected":"true"},{"id":11,"slug":"nature","title":"Nature","description":"","parent":0,"post_count":3,"selected":"true"},{"id":12,"slug":"night","title":"Night","description":"","parent":0,"post_count":8,"selected":"true"},{"id":10,"slug":"old","title":"Old","description":"","parent":0,"post_count":3,"selected":"true"},{"id":3,"slug":"people","title":"People","description":"","parent":0,"post_count":15,"selected":"true"},{"id":9,"slug":"rooftops","title":"Rooftops","description":"","parent":0,"post_count":2,"selected":"true"},{"id":8,"slug":"weird","title":"Weird","description":"","parent":0,"post_count":1,"selected":"true"}]
```

to posts objects which have multiple categories (e.g. post Zoomed Houses has the Day,Architecture categories)

Comment: I upadted the plunkr here http://plnkr.co/edit/KbBg67 ...I will leave this question as it is and ask another question regarding the refining of the filter.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that is interested:

I solved this by simply catching the error thrown due to undefined object, and then I throw an error like `throw "Object not yet loaded. Trying again...";`

```
app.filter('translate', function() {
        return function(input) {
            try {
                var index = input.toUpperCase();
                if (app.translation[index]) {
                    if (input[0] === index[0])
                        return app.translation[index].capitalize();
                    return app.translation[index];
                }
                return input;
            }
            catch(err) {
                 throw "Translation not loaded yet, trying again...";
            }
        };
    })
app.run(function($http) {
        $http.get("translations/" + "NB_ENG" + ".json", {
                cache: true
            }).success(function(data) {         
                app.translation = data;
                console.info("Translation loaded.");
            }).error(function(q,w,e) {
                app.translation = 1;
                console.error("Failed getting translation: "+q + " | " + w + " | " + e + " | ");
            });
    });
```

Here I am awaiting the translation file, before being able to translate all the words. Angular runs the filter again and again  until it gets a valid return.