# Angular Filter Improvement (pure JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filtering

**I have this plnkr here http://plnkr.co/edit/KbBg67.**

You can see the categories object format and the posts object format.
It is a angular demo app based on a Wordpress backbone, from where I get my info using JSON.

Problems with this:

- the way the filter is implemented, this is another question on stackoverflow, here [AngularJS promises and timing with custom filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18263648/angularjs-promises-and-timing-with-custom-filters)
- the filter duplicates all my posts, also asked in the previous question.
- **the filter hides the items, but they won't show back again.**
- **the filtering method is not OK, this is what I actually need help with**

---

### ***Desired behavior:***

***Any post can have more than two categories, one is day or night, the rest their specific category***

I have to main categories: Day & Night, at start only one needs to be selected, day. Whichever one of these two categories I selected posts that match that need to show.

After I selected one of these two categories, I can refine further with the subcategories, funny, weird, architecture, rooftops etc.

Day&Night are somehow imperative categories, if Day is selected everything that has Night mustn't show up.

But if I have Day selected, and I select Funny, Posts that have Day&Funny Selected must show up, also if after funny I select weird, posts matching the Day/Funny/Weird must show up.

It's really convoluted to explain but the behavior is pretty straight forward, good UX, I just can't wrap my head around that filter to make it like this.

I don't want only the code, I want to understand how to make this :) to avoid future questions. I realize this is pure JavaScript at this point.

As a background, I am a frontend developer that turned recently to Angular and I am dipping my toes heavily in it :).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I managed to remove the onscreen duplication, apparently on each matching category I would push the post in the result array, so if I'd had 4 categories for a post, that post would have appeared 4 times, fixed that, moved the pushed statement from inside the individual categories for statement into the posts for statement. Plnkr updated, no progress on the other issues, and in the console when I check to see how many categories does each post have, I still get two loops without explanation.

Comment: Regarding the items not appearing again when I RE-select a checkbox, I tend to think that the posts array is actually emptied out, or only with the results in it, and on RE-selecting a category box no posts are found matching that category. Am i right?